# How to create a screen without a system bar at the bottom in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I would like to test my app in android 4.2.2,I know certain device comes with system bar along screen and others don't.I would like to know how to test those system bar that doesn't come along screen.Please provide your assistance in fixing the emulator for this,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old good question. If changing theme does not fits your needs, please refer to these question asked before:

[Easy way to hide system bar on Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445157/easy-way-to-hide-system-bar-on-android-ics/16401655#16401655)

[Is there a way to hide the system bar in Android 3.0? It's an internal device and I'm managing navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-an)

[is it possible to hide the system bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801928/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-system-bar)

and others.

Note that for some HW Devices/Android version, the system bar can't be hidden at all! You need to root the device and manage some complex operation to get the system bar off...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme of the Project from manifest file..it will solve your problem