# Hide notification bar for a specific activity in android 4.2.2 (iBall Kitkat Tablet)

Tags: android, tablet, android-4.4-kitkat, kiosk-mode

I did a lot of search regarding the topic, but previous stack overflow answers didn't solved my problem.
I am developing kiosk mode for an application (Targeted to run on Iball Kitkat tablet- android 4.2.2), and I want to apply kiosk mode to a single activity only. I want to hide/disable/prevent expansion of notification bar of tablet.

What I have tried is :-

- [is it possible to hide the system bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801928/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-system-bar)
- [Is there a way to hide the system/navigation bar in Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926767/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-navigation-bar-in-android-ics)

and many more

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in your Activity -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Your app will go full screen without notification bar

Comment: I added this code to my oncreate() but it throws exception  android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Put `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before the `super.OnCreatesavedInstanceState)`